# Multiple upload files in Oracle apex 4.1

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-plugin

How to upload multiple files in Oracle Apex 4.1, currently single file is getting uploaded in the existing page of an application. Please suggest any quick way to get this done.

Comment: Can we use SQLLDR with unix to zip files and then load it to the DB through Oracle Apex Application page?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to - before loading - merge all input files into one, and then upload one "large" file.

Apex 4.x doesn't support what what I'm going to write next.

---

Another - probably better for you - would be to

- edit **Data Load Source** page (generated by the wizard),
- navigate to the "File Browse ..." item (let's call it `P1_FILE_NAME`),
- go to the "Settings" section and
- enable **Allow Multiple Files**

This option works from 5.x onwards, so - if you're still on 4.x, I'd suggest you to upgrade to a more recent version (why not 19.x)?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer.
I already worked on 18+ versions, but here no option is there to upgrade as of now.
There can be an option through plugin (jquery), about which I am not familiar with.
I tried to get some result with the plugin but no clue till now.